# Asignarle datos a un DataGridView

Tags: c#

Hola estoy tratando de asignarle datos a un DataGridView por medio de una lista, pero solo logro pasarle datos por única vez, pero necesito que al agregar varias registros a la lista me cargue todos los asignados a la lista y asignarle la lista al DGV.

```
var p = new Persona()
        {
            Id = Utilidades.RowId,
            Nombre = Utilidades.RowDes
        };

        listPersona.Add(p);

        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvPersona.Rows)
        {
            foreach (var item in listPersona)
            {
                row.Cells["ColCodigo"].Value = item.Id;
                row.Cells["ColName"].Value = item.Nombre;
            }
        }
```

Comment: El foreach te ejecuta el código por cada elemento de la colección. Por lo que estás repitiendo la asignación al DataSource tantas veces como tengas elementos en `listPersona`. Quita el foreach y ejecuta `gcPrueba3.DataSource = listPersona;` cada vez que agregues un elemento a la colección `listPersona`.

Comment: @FreddyHdz De esa manera solo me carga un item.

Comment: Pues eso es un poco más complicado, necesitas implementar el patrón de diseño observer. aquí te dejo el link de la teoría. https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_(patr%C3%B3n_de_dise%C3%B1o)

Answer (score 0):

Lo solucione de la siguiente manera.

```
var p = new Persona()
        {
            Id = Utilidades.RowId,
            Nombre = Utilidades.RowDes
        };

        gcPrueba3.DataSource = null;
        listPersona.Add(p);
        gcPrueba3.DataSource = listPersona;
```

Comment: Tal como te dijo @FreddyHdz en un comentario